# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value that is not equal to the supplied origin but it is

Tags: javascript, youtube, cors

I have a problem with CORS, i'm trying to redirect a youtube video to another youtube video using a chrome extension.
The only problem is this
[www.youtube.com is not equal to www.youtube.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df6ai.png)

I tried setting the origin as https://www.youtube.com, https://r6---sn-hpa7zn76.googlevideo.com and even the same domain https://r1---sn-uxaxpu5ap5-bv51.googlevideo.com.
The value is never the right one.
So i have no idea what should i set, not to raise any error.

No, "*" is not a solution. Youtube doesn't allow wildcard since "credentials mode is 'include'".

If you need the code or/and test it.
https://github.com/Super99Master/Wait-it-s-all-Rick-Roll/blob/main/background.js

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the issue here isn't on "what you're sending" or "who you're sending it to", but I think the issue is that YouTube might have a CORS policy on "who's sending it".

Additionally, how are you redirecting it? Do you have a code sample?

Comment: I will asume that you already read about this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/) ?

Comment: @NeuronButter with "return {redirectUrl: link}",
i use chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest to capture the link of the original video
and then replace it with the link of another video via the return {redirectUrl: link}.
The new link is a valid one, if you open it in a new tab it runs without problems.

Comment: @Tch this seems a better way to make the extension but not the solution to the problem?! the problem is not how i redirect, i think.

Comment: Change the request URL to the `https://ri---sn-uxaxpuSap5-bv51.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=…` URL. The exact cause of the problem described in the question is, the request is getting redirected across origins. You’re sending the request to `https://r6---sn-hpa7zn76.googlevideo.com` but it gets redirected to `https://ri---sn-uxaxpuSap5-bv51.googlevideo.com`. Those are two different domains. And when that happens, the browser changes the requesting origin to null; that is, the browser no longer recognizes `https://www.youtube.com` as the requesting origin. That’s why there’s no match.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I love you, but i already tried it and it gives the same error.
I tryed using the extension "ModHeader" so that i didn't have to code everything to test it.